# dynamically change BackgroundColor of CardView

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

It is written in documentation that the BackgroundColor of CardView can be set in XML with `card_view:cardBackgroundColor`. However, I cannot find a corresponding method to change the background dynamically.

Using `mCardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(75, 102,80,67));` will cause the CardView to lose the rounded corner and shadow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Providing background color to the child class of cardview will leave the padded parts in case if the card view has any, without color and this is not a good approach.

Dynamically change the card view color as below, assuming you have a adapter to load the list in the card view.

In constructor of adapters Viewholder class

```
mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
```

In onBindViewHolder method of the adapter class :

```
holder.mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // will change the background color of the card view to green
```

Where holder is the object of your viewholder class.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work nicely by setting the background of the CardView's child:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/card_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then

```
    View cardLayout = mCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
    cardLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: It does not work as expected as long as the cardview has a cardCornerRadius. Still looking for a better solution.

Comment: @manutudescends are you sure? it works for me and I have used `card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"` in my xml

Comment: 2dp is too small to notice it. Try with 10dp and you will see that the solution is not correct.

Comment: It worked for me with radius but I had set `android:backgroundTintandroid:backgroundTint` and removing it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using only the Color.GREEN you will not have the result you expect.

Use **ContextCompat.getColor(@NonNull context: Context, @ColorRes id: Int)**

It returns a color associated with a particular resource ID

```
View cardLayout = mCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
cardLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, Color.GREEN));
```

Answer (score -2):

There will be an API in the upcoming release. For now, your only option is using XML.

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: Please add this solution when API will be released.